Win 10- Convenient method to move "known folders" to a new drive for multiple users
I have a small network. The client machines, running either Home or Pro version of Windows 10, all have the same user accounts configured.
I am looking for a convenient way to switch a selected set of the "Known folders" (i.e. Documents, Templates, Videos, Music etc.) over to a different drive, for all of the "real" user accounts.
This is possible manually in windows by changing the "Location" property of each folder but it's a laborious task, as you need to log in as each user in turn and then manually move all the folders one at a time.
This seems like something that would be a fairly standard thing to do, but so far I have not found a good solution.
The nearest to is is this discussion on Stackoverflow, and the associated gist on GitHub. However this script needs 225 lines of Powershell code to achieve moving one known folder, for the currently logged-in user, so the process is no more time efficient than using the normal Windows UI.
Surely there has to be an easier way?

Please note that asking for software products or other tools to solve a problem is specifically off topic on this site. You can ask how to solve this problem, note the laborious solution you've found, and ask for better ways to do this, all without asking that we recommend software tools to do this for you. Without that bit about asking for tools, yours is a good question, so I recommend making that change to stop the close votes.

That seems like an odd distinction ("how to do X" vs. "what tool best facilitates X") given that achieving anythin on a computer involves using one or more software "tools", but ok, I can change the title.

I don't see it. I recommend you read the Help section for a fuller explanation of the reasons behind this. The basics are that knowing a tool name might help you today, but what about when the tool's dev retires, or changes direction in a significant way? That sort of answer does not serve the purpose of this site, which may differ from what you expect. Further, knowing HOW to solve a problem, tool or no, is more helpful to you. IF a tool solves a problem, that can be a good answer AND if some built-in method works, that is also a good answer.

The location of the Shell Folders is kept at
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
(and at
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Backup )

One could make a .reg file to change a batch at once, though that script would need to be run by each user.
For one user, make changes manually to the location of each of the Shell Folders, then export the key
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
to a .reg file. Import that file for each user.
N.B.
This relies on paths being set by Environment Variables, e.g., %USERPROFILE%\Documents for My Documents, which is the usual case. However, if someone has edited a value to use the absolute path, rather than %USERPROFILE%, that would not work.
Also, note that any mistake could make Windows unusable. Make a full drive image before implementing these changes.

During my research into this I came upon this article: The long and sad story of the Shell Folders key which describes in some detail how the registry "Shell Folders" key is a historical appendage, and that even "User Shell Folders" shouldn't be relied on.

Unfortunately therefore the only Microsoft-approved way to move known folders is with an API function (SHGetSpecialFolderLocation) that doesn't have a Powershell binding, and hence you end up eitherr drowning in Powershell wrapper code, or needing to learn C++ and Visual Studio just to move some user directories.
That's not a viable option from my perspective, so I think i'm left with either of two "hacky options" (write those registry keys, or try using symbolic links as used to work in Windows 7), or just bite the bullet and spend 1/2 a day moving everything over manually.

Also, given that i ideally want to move the known folders for multiple users in a single operation, what are the interactions between the HKLM registry branch for a user named (say) "X", and the HKCU branch if that user happens to be the user that is currently logged in and manipulating the registry?
In other words, if I set up a script to move folders for 6 people, and one of those people happens to be me (the person with admin rights), do I have to be careful to make the same change to the HKCU branch as well as the HKLM one, or will windows keep these two in sync automatically?
